# Парсинг ошибки из терминала

Tags: python, парсер

хотел сделать парсинг ошибок из терминала. Расскажу подробней: нужно парсить ошибку с текстом, который хотим искать. То-есть, я задал текст: "error", но в терминале выводится: "good work, man!" - его мы не берём, а потом выводится: "error: jbcdsbj" - его мы берём. Нужно, чтобы это всё ещё записывалось в какой ни-будь файл. Можно вообще такое реализовать?

Comment: Сергей, просьба добавить ваш код. Вы уже написали какой-либо код или пока у вас задание реализовано только в виде текста на русском языке ?

Comment: Пока в виде текста на русском языке.

Comment: Нет, Сергей, мы не можем написать за вас код с самого начала ( с нуля ). Почитайте книжки, напишите хотя бы пару строк своего кода. Затем возвращайтесь, покажите нам свой код. Тогда и поговорим

Comment: А я просил целый код? Я просил помочь с функцией, которая будет всё это делать во время выполнения того или иного кода.

Comment: Нельзя написать просто функцию в вакууме, необходимо видеть кто, как и когда будет её вызывать